# What is exact difference between array.map() and forEach() when updating LWC properties?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-datatable

A lightning-datatable fetches data with array.map() but not with array.forEach(). Can someone please tell me the practical difference between the two methods and why forEach() is not working here? Data is pulling same in browser console while using both methods.

[image: Datatable not fetching when forEach() is used]

[image: Datatable fetching when map() is used]

Here is the js file from which data is fetched into datatable component-

```
connectedCallback() {
    getPCRecords()
        .then(result => {
    if (result && result.length > 0) {
                this.data = result.map((record) => {
                    return {
                        ...record,
                        nameUrl: '/' + record.Id,
        };
                });
            } else {
                this.error = 'No records to display';
            }

        }).catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
            console.log('Error --', error);
        });

}
```

Here is .js file from which data is not being fetched -

```
connectedCallback() {
    getPCRecords()
        .then(result => {
           if (result && result.length > 0) {
                console.log('result--', result);
                result.forEach(element => {
                    const obj = {
                        ...element,
                        nameUrl: '/' + element.Id,
        };
                    this.data.push(obj);
                });
                console.log(‘data — ', this.data);
            } else {
                this.error = 'No records to display';
            }}).catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
            console.log('Error --', error);
        });
```

}

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. This question is about JavaScript and would be better addressed on a different community site, such as [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

Comment: @PhilW It's Salesforce-technology-specific JavaScript, and is perfectly fine here. We've been answering SFDC-related JS questions for ages.

Comment: I hope we don't get into the aggressive question closing and downvoting that characterises the main site. In my mind this a reasonable (and interesting) question.

Comment: Honestly, I did not read far enough before voting to close. The summary and first paragraph were actually misleading as to what the question was really about and, yes, it is worth answering here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> executes a provided function once for each array element.

[`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> **creates a new array** populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Since a new array is created, the value of `this.data` changes (it holds just a reference to the array) when you assign the result of `Array.map()` to that property, moreover since it is used in the template, the component rerenders and displays the new values.

In the component that uses `Array.forEach()`, the value of `this.data` never changes. No matter how many values have been pushed into the array, the value of the property `data` doesn't change, because it's always the reference to the same array. Therefore no rerender is triggered.

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reactivity-fields.html) states:

> **When manipulating complex types like objects and arrays, you must create a new object and assign it to the field for the change to be detected**.
> To avoid such issues when working with complex objects, use the `@track` decorator to deeply tracks mutations made to the field value.

In order to replicate the behavior of `Array.map()` in the second component, you should create a new array, fill it, then assign its reference to `this.data`:

```
connectedCallback() {
    getPCRecords()
        .then(result => {
            if (result && result.length > 0) {
                console.log('result--', result);
                const data = []; // Create a new array
                result.forEach(element => {
                    const obj = {
                        ...element,
                        nameUrl: '/' + element.Id,
                    };
                    data.push(obj); // push the elements in the new array
                });
                this.data = data; // replace the reference
                console.log('data — ', this.data);
            } else {
                this.error = 'No records to display';
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
            console.log('Error --', error);
        });
}
```

Comment: It worked when I created a new array. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The LWR (Lightning Web Runtime) only detects shallow changes by default. In other words, it'll detect that you have a new array (which `Array.prototype.map` creates), but it won't detect changes to an existing array by default; you need to use @track (see [Reactivity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reactivity_fields)).

So, you need to either `@track` or use `Array.prototype.map`. It doesn't matter which you do, they're roughly the same performance-wise.

## Option 1

Using `forEach`/`push`, you can change:

```
data;
```

to

```
@track data;
```

Make sure you also import it:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
```

However, note that you're adding to the existing Array. Every time your wire method refreshes its data, you'll end up duplicating data. You don't generally want to do this. This is one reason to avoid `forEach`/`push` loops.

---

## Option 2

Changing the object reference works as well. `Array.prototype.map` creates a *new* map using the callback function to transform the inputs. Note that `forEach`/`push` is *slower* than `map` for its intended purpose (which you're doing in your own code). You use `forEach` if you want to modify some/all elements of an array, and use `map` if you want to create a copy, instead. In LWC, we'll almost always want to mutate `data`, so it makes sense to use `map` rather than `forEach`/`push`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering my question. I tried using @track. It did not work. It only worked when I created a new array and pushed values into it. I might have missed something.